# Métodos polimórficos podem ser implementados na existência de herança?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos

Não estou certo se respondi corretamente ao exercício:

(Três classes, `Funcionário`, `Mensalista`, e `Horista` implementam a operação `calcularPagamento()`, porém, de forma diferente. Isto é possível graças ao recurso de
polimorfismo. Sendo assim, pode-se afirmar que qual o tipo de associação existe das
classes `Mensalista` e `Horista` com a classe `Funcionário`?

> I -Agregação, pois não é possível criar métodos polimórficos em outro
> tipo de associação
>
> **II Herança, pois métodos polimórficos podem ser implementados na existência desse tipo de associação.** *(EU MARQUEI ESSA COMO CORRETA, pq tabela horista e mensalista herdam os atributos da funcionario , mas a III ao meu ver tbm está certa, pelo o que eu li de materiais)*
>
> III Composição, pois métodos polimórficos apenas podem ser
> implementados neste tipo de Associação
>
> IV Herança, pois o polimorfismo permite que classes herdem atributos e métodos de outras classes.

Comment: [Edite a pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/531017/edit) e coloque a justificativa junto, a gente diz se está certa ou não.

Comment: apesar que eu acho que a III tbm se encaxaria mas não sei "composição" é o correto , já que algo assim seria de agregação pelo meu ver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adianto que não entendo muito de polimorfismo em geral, sei mais no caso do Java.

Sei que pode ser obtido através de herança.

O supertipo (eu diria superclasse mas o tipo pode ser uma interface do Java, por exemplo) estabelece um método abstrato ou virtual, ou mesmo fornece uma implementação concreta desse método no caso de uma classe, com nível de acesso não-privado (público, protegido, etc.), que pode ser sobrescrita (substituída) nos seus subtipos.

A escolha de qual versão do método vai ser chamada é feita em tempo de execução, por isso um mesmo objeto (ok, uma referência para um objeto) de tipo `Animal` pode `emitirSom()` de maneiras diferentes se for uma `Vaca` ou um `Cachorro`. É o chamado "polimorfismo de tempo de execução" ou *runtime polymorphism*.

Então a resposta II está correta.

Porém a III não está correta. Composição é um tipo de agregação "tem um". Carro tem um motor. Pessoa tem braços. Entendo que não cabe polimorfismo. Caberia delegação, padrão de projeto *Strategy*, etc. Mesmo que isso fosse considerado um tipo de polimorfismo (e nunca ouvi falar que poderia ser), não é a única forma como diz a alternativa. Então errada.

Agregação é uma relacionamento de "posse" bem fraca, no qual as partes são bastante independentes entre si e não há posse exclusiva por parte do agregado. Por exemplo, `Carro` agrega-se a `Casa`, mas podem bem existir de maneira isolada um do outro e um carro pode inclusive ser compartilhado entre mais de uma casa. Também não cabe polimorfismo, pois não há método a ser escolhido para executar em tempo de execução.

Por fim, a IV diz que o polimorfismo permite que se herdem atributos e métodos, não é o polimorfismo que permite isso e sim a herança (de subclasse ou de subtipo). Portanto errada.

Em termos de modelagem, eu não modelaria `Mensalista` e `Horista` como classes, pois são características muito dinâmicas, um cliente pode mudar de um para o outro ao longo do tempo e não faz muito sentido mudar em consequência disso a classe do mesmo, que deveria ser uma característica mais estável. Vale só para ilustrar o problema mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado de verdade por tirar a minha duvida ,estava até agora tentando difenciar .

Comment: Fiz uns ajustes na resposta, estava com uns conceitos errados. Favor reler.